# Ubuntu16.04 - Unmet dependencies - apt-get -f install raises error too

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04. I accidentally run this command: `sudo apt-get purge python3.6` because there were problems with manually installed `python 3.6` and now everything raises error.

```
milano@milano-Aspire-VN7-591G:~$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:18.04.11.10).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu1) but 1.5.66ubuntu1 is to be installed
 glib-networking : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.55.0) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
 glib-networking-services : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.55.0) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
 libcommon-sense-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
                        Depends: perl (< 5.22.2~) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-vfs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libgoa-1.0-0b : Depends: libgoa-1.0-common (= 3.18.3-1ubuntu2) but 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.52) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.25.4) but 3.18.3-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgtk2-appindicator-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libimage-magick-q16-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-libidn-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libperl5.22 : Depends: perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but it is not installable
 libproc-processtable-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
               Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.6-dev : Depends: python3.6 (= 3.6.9-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:16.04.12) but 1:18.04.11.10 is to be installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.168.9) but 3.192.1.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try to run the command:  `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
milano@milano-Aspire-VN7-591G:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu1) but 1.5.66ubuntu1 is installed
 glib-networking : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.55.0) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is installed
 glib-networking-services : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.55.0) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is installed
 libcommon-sense-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
                        Depends: perl (< 5.22.2~) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-vfs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libgoa-1.0-0b : Depends: libgoa-1.0-common (= 3.18.3-1ubuntu2) but 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.52) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 is installed
                        Depends: libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.25.4) but 3.18.3-1ubuntu2 is installed
 libgtk2-appindicator-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libimage-magick-q16-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-libidn-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 libperl5.22 : Depends: perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but it is not installable
 libproc-processtable-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
               Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not installed
 python3.6-dev : Depends: python3.6 (= 3.6.9-1~18.04) but it is not installed
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:16.04.12) but 1:18.04.11.10 is installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.168.9) but 3.192.1.7 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Do you have idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to make sure that there aren’t newer versions of the required packages.

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

before

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```